# Omitting return type and argument type in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

> If a return or argument type isn't explicitly declared, it’s assumed to be the default type for methods and messages — an `id`.

So there is no question about how it works technically, but is it ever advisable to omit the type or is it simply bad practice? Does Apple have any official guidelines regarding this?

Answer (score 3):

It's bad practice. It is a hangover from the early days of C. Don't do it, zero upside.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe - It really is back to C not Objective-C, it was just modified for the latter.

Comment: Excuse me for being too fast with this correction. I thought you'd have to mean Objective-C since there's no `id` type in C.

Answer (score 1):

It's very uncommon and thus not recommended. I've not yet come across a single occurrence in one of Apple's headers.

It's a bit like the C standard allows to call an unknown function (one without prototype): possible—but not advisable.

Also, there's less and less occasions where returning an id is a good idea.

Comment: have you ever looked at NSArray header?

Comment: more or less recently added: `+(id)JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`

Comment: @peko At least the current SDKs contain no NSArray header that omits the return type.

Comment: Ah, maybe both of you are referring to my "less and less occasions". I said less and less to make clear that it's not commonly useful. Of course there *are* situations where there's not yet a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying types helps the compiler keep an eye on what you're doing, it makes no difference at runtime, (but your app will crash if you send objects to objects that can't receive it).

*id* simply means *any object*

You can use **id** if you need to handle several types of objects somewhere, but you better know what you're doing here and probably want to use **introspection** to prevent your application from crash due to a message sent to non compliant object.